# ¿como mandar el parametro Authorization desde una petición en el header en agular 7?

Tags: http, angular7, headers

estoy intentando hacer una petición a un microservicio desde angular 7, lo cual el método que estoy tratando consultar como parámetros me pide mandar en Header el parametro Authorization con el valor del token,
como lo muestro en la siguiente imagen [image: asi estoy intentado hacer la petición]

asi estoy intentando hacer mi petición, lo cual me response el siguiente error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien tiene la solución a este error o que es lo que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas tratando de hacer una petición post tienes que añadir los datos que quieres enviar como segundo parámetro a la petición:

```
return this.http.post(endpoint, datos, httpOptions);
```

si realmente es una peticion get modifica el método:

```
return this.http.get(endpoint, httpOptions);
```

Más información aquí:

https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

espero eso te ayude.